# Smart or stupid way to do development is easy to maintain?

Tags: architecture

Here is the problem, I have an xml, which require me to transfer xml to an object. 
I can manually convert the xml to the requires object, the object get which attribute, and generate, and the developer can get everything by seeing the class.

But the smarter way is to loop every xml node name, and become an attribute name, the set the value by program, it uses less code, but in the development process, can't get access by seeing the class.

Comment: you're doing it wrong.... it is better to ask for a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Java, you might want to use [java.beans.XMLDecoder](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/beans/XMLDecoder.html) rather than rolling your own code.

Answer (score 0):

If you like, you could use a map which uses strings as keys.